# How can I best impose image sizing rules for all figures?

Tags: graphics

I want all my images to be the same size. Is there a nice way to impose this rule in the preamble?

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{my_image}
  \caption{describe my image}
  \label{fig:my_image}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 5):

By adding

```
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[<default settings>,#1]{#2}}
```

to your document preamble (after loading [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)), you can set up default settings to be included for *every* figure.

For example, you can change `<default settings>` to be `width=6cm, height=3cm` (say) and all figures will have a width of 6cm and a height of 3cm, *unless* you specify other local options to override this. That is, the above redefinition still allows you to use `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{<image>}` which will set `<image>` to have width 2cm (and height 3cm).

The above method is similar to adding

```
\setkeys{Gin}{<default settings>}
```

to your preamble, which sets the default key-values for the `Gin` family (used for the `in`clusion of `G`raphics.

Comment: Thanks that's works great but for one thing. When I try to override it on my front page logo with `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{<image>}` this does not seem to work. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @Magpie: I tried both approaches and they allow for local overriding. You must be doing something different...

Comment: Yes, I missed out the `,#1` bit somehow. Thanks for clarifying.